# Simple approximation of Sine

Tags: c, trigonometry

I'm looking for an approximation for Sine which is correct at `x == 0` and `x == 90` or `x == pi/2` and within 5% otherwise.

I have no space for look-up tables.

Comment: What's wrong with the standard sin functions?

Comment: You could implement your approximation using Taylor series

Comment: We are no coding service and library recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @JohnZwinck probably for a fast approximating SSE/AVX implementation.

Comment: @Olaf C'on man, it's almost weekend ;-)

Comment: @JohnZwinck It's not available.  (I'm doing fixed-point calculations on a chip with wither 64 bytes or 1Kb RAM).

Comment: A small lookup table with say15 entries and linear interpolation ?

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, I shouldn't have asked, but I'm going to leave the question up as it has received good answers.

Comment: Check out [the approximation here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltTaTT6aUls&t=586s&ab_channel=MathematicsVisuallyExplained)you can find a nice visualization including the error within your range.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You seem to be able to use [Bhaskara I's sine approximation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhaskara_I's_sine_approximation_formula) :

```
float x;
float sinx = 4 * x * (180 - x) / (40500 - x * (180 - x));
```

The error stays within 2%.

Very fast and can be optimized (by hand).

Comment: It does say *within 5% otherwise*.

Comment: @Kh40tiK I misread (on purpose :-) Here's a better answer.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltTaTT6aUls&ab_channel=MathematicsVisuallyExplained) you can find a nice visualization of the approximation including the error.

Comment: @flatronka Very cool; thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Since the derivative of a `sin` is `cos` which never goes above 1, and 5% is 1 / 20, a lookup table with `20 * pi / 2 = 32` points would satisfy your requirements. Are you sure you can't spare even 32 bytes of your RAM to store it?

Comment: I have either 64 or 1KB RAM in total.

Comment: And how much of that is free?

Comment: @meaning-matters your answer is cool, but your comment doesn't contribute to the discussion about *my* answer and serves only the purpose of self-promotion.

Comment: This is for https://hackaday.io/contest/18215-the-1kb-challenge so I'm trying hard to keep code-size and data to a minimum.  I will be hand-optimising the generated ARM assembly, where I can.

Comment: @chrisdew Oh, ok then. I was in my pragmatic mood when answering this, but if you really need to save the last byte, you can beat a LUT for sure. BTW, you may want to add the MCU model you're considering to the question, since the best answer could be MCU-specific.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: More likely ROM/Flash.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I can think to do this is to use `Taylor/Maclaurin Expansions`.

These form a polynomial which represents an ever-improving approximation to a function.

In general you pick a value of the function about which you want to approximate via Taylor series.

For example around `x = 0` radians `sin(x) = x - x^3 / 3! + x^5 / 5!`. The series is infinite and the more terms you include the closer to the true value you will get.

I suggest that you might have to form several of these Taylor expansions at "convenient" places (30, 60, 45, 90 degrees). And then use the function that you angle is closest to.

Comment: "And then use the function that you angle is closest to." - so...like a lookup table?  ;-)

Comment: Well you wouldn't have to store anything this way. Just define 4 functions and have an `if` to decide which one to call.

Answer (score 0):

Found with a quick linear fit.

```
1.00003 x - 0.000312267 x^2 - 0.165537 x^3 - 0.00203937 x^4 +  0.010286 x^5 - 0.000961693 x^6
```

This maximum error is 3%.

Comment: Thanks, but is this competitive with Bhaskara I's sine approximation?  It looks like it requires 12 multiplications, but then Bhaskara's requires a division.

Comment: @chrisdew Definitely not, because I didn't googled for it :)

Comment: @chrisdew also no need 12 mults, just do something like `a+x*(b+x*(c+x*(...)))`